# Calculating the variance of a regressor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variance

I am trying to calculate the variance of the predictors in a model with 540 observations. From the predictor matrix (X_blocked), I want to take the second column (the first column is for the intercept, the second column for the first predictor), calculate it's variance, and store the value in a variable:

```
blocked_pred1_var = np.sum(X_blocked[:, 1] - np.mean(X_blocked[:, 1]) ** 2) / 539
```

But this gives me a false number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses are wrongly positioned. Currently, you are squaring the mean and subtracting it from your predicted values. You need to subtract the mean from predicted values and then square it.

```
blocked_pred1_var = np.sum((X_blocked[:, 1] - np.mean(X_blocked[:, 1])) ** 2) / 539
```